# moduleNotFoundError: "Arduino"

Tags: directory, libraries

I have just discovered the wonderful world of microprocessors and microcontrollers. Since I am still learning python, and it is my first language, I want to learn how to control microcontrollers using python, even though most use C++.

My search led me to the Python-Arduino Command API library available on GitHub. I used the following command to install the library.

> > > pip install Arduino-python

***Additional Information***: I am using Anaconda Navigator.

The problem:
When I try to import the new library using Spyder which is running python 3.7 I get this error:

> > > **File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import Arduino
> > >         File "C:\Users\daypa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Arduino__init__.py", line 4, in 
> > >           from arduino import Arduino, Shrimp
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arduino'**

From the message I see that the file "arduino" is in the same directory as the other packages in my anaconda's "base root" environment.

However when I check that same environment using Anaconda, I do not see it there.
py.serial is there, although im not sure if that came with initial installation of anaconda.

I have also tried installing it using:

> > > conda install -c auto arduino-python

which is the command shown in Anaconda's website.